# SQL Server Stored procedure performance varies one server to another server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure created in two different servers, one is installed in my local machine and another one is installed another machine.
When i am trying to execute in my local server it will take 1 sec to execute but when i am trying to connect other instance and execute the same stored procedure it will take 15 seconds to execute.

Kindly let me know the reason and how to improve the performance

Comment: You need to add more details as to what your stored procedure is doing? Its definition, the tables involved etc etc

Comment: You mentioned 'local server' and 'other instance' -- can you tell us more about potential differences between these machines and the nature of the connection to the 'other instance'?

Comment: There are multiple elements which influence execution time. But I would look for missing indexes on your second instance. If that is not the case, it may be because your data is not stored "the same" on the second instance's HDD disks (maybe the data is more "spread" on the disks rather than being "clustered", which generates additional time for the HDD head to move around the disks etc.) .. and there could be so many more other reasons..

Comment: Are your sure that the database on both systems is identical in structure? Is the amount of data roughly the same? Try to take BAK and install the identical db on both systems. Same result?

Comment: Are they the same procedure ?  Is their environment the same (tables, size, indexes) ? Are the session settings the same ? There are way too many participents.   So first, make sure that the environments are the same.  Also that the network isn't an issue as it's the remote execution that has the bad performance (did you check a local execution on the other server ? )